# View over surface view : Works on some android version

Tags: java, android, view

I'm actually making an android app which uses a SurfaceView to draw the Camera.
I want to add some views over it.

In fact, i already done it. It works on my android 4.1.1. All my views are drawn over the Camera.

But when i try it on a Android 2.3, it don't works anymore.
Depends of what i'm doing, it shows a part of the view in the left-top corner (As if the parent layout were too small)

Here is the xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.example.calculatrice.CustomCameraView
        android:id="@+id/cameraView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/poiGroup">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bBack"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I have a button, wich is perfectly shown over the camera.
I put the views i want to draw under that button (with "layout(x,x,x,x)"). They appear cuted (or don't appear, depend).

```
Here is some usefull code
//In oncreate method
     customCamera = (CustomCameraView)this.findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
```

//Create view and add it to the layout

`public void initObjects()
{
    listPoiMarker = new LinkedList<POIMarker>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < names.length && names[i] != null)
    {
        Location locTmp = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        locTmp.setLatitude(coordonates[0][i]);
        locTmp.setLongitude(coordonates[1][i]);
        POIMarker tmp = new POIMarker(getApplicationContext());
        tmp.setPoiId(id[i]);
        tmp.setId(i);
        tmp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tmp.setName(names[i]);
        tmp.setLocation(locTmp);
        tmp.posScreenY = 100 + (i) * 60;
        listPoiMarker.add(tmp);
        tmp.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.poiGroup)).addView(tmp);
        tmp.layout(50, 50, 250, 250);
        i++;
    }
}`

Not exactly what i do. In fact the layout function is somewhere else.
But it's the same.

That works fine in Android 4.1.1, but not in 2.2 or 2.3
I looking for a solution for about 2 days. I tried 999 things, none worked.
That's why i come here to ask some help.

(Here is an example of what it does : http://drawsave.com/19Z
I don't want to add a picture.. Take too long

The red thing is the view i add. It's supposed to be a rectangle. But it's cuted, on 2.2 | 2.3 ..
)

Thanks for help

EDIT:

I found a way to fix it.
How ?
I added a transparent background to the layout containing the views. So it don't resize anymore, it keeps the right size.
(Yep, that's not really logical, but it works)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just wanted to let you know you can answer your own question by clicking the button labeled `Answer Your Own Question` allowing you to mark it as the accepted answer.